# Arrange records in grid formation

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I want my payroll system report to prints ID cards of employees. I'd like to arrange them into a grid on a single page as seen below. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Actually I myself got an Idea by using the option format details section with multiple columns and selecting across then down option. Any way thanks for going through this problem. In case if there is any other trick I would like to discuss about it.

Comment: Why note use Mail label option when you create  your report ? Like this : http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000007348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: The best way to achieve this is to go to the section expert for the Details section and activate *Format With Multiple Columns*. This will activate the Layout tab where you can configure the correct measurements and orientation for your data:

[image: Common and Layout Tabs]

In theory you could also achieve the same method with subreports, or some really wacky code involving *NEXT* and *PREVIOUS* - but formatting with multiple columns is hands down the least confusing and the least work.